# Netlify doesn't display all website pages

Tags: reactjs, web, deployment, web-deployment, netlify

I am using Netlify to deploy a website. It was built with ReactJS and locally everything works. After deploying it on Netlify only the landing page works.

The website is a simple static website for hosting my portfolio.

The main website is [www.myname.com](http://www.myname.com) while projects are located on [www.myname.com/project-name-case-study](http://www.myname.com/project-name-case-study)

Anything under [www.myname.com/project-name-case-study](http://www.myname.com/project-name-case-study) leads to a "Page Not Found" screen. I'm just not sure where to even start here. I'm new to website deployment

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out. The issue was specifically related to React-Router. [This freeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-react-router-based-app-to-netlify/) shows how to easily fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-react-router-based-app-to-netlify/) mentioned:
"Create a new file with the name **_redirects** inside the **public** folder of our project and add the following contents inside it:"

```
/* /index.html 200
```